# Error while transferring null decimal value to Azure Data Warehouse using polybase enabled in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

We have Azure Data Factory v2 pipeline which transfers data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Data Warehouse using polybase enabled.

Source table contains null decimal values but when ADF tries to process null value it is giving an error :

> ,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=107090,State=1,Message=Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed.\n(/24b40621-2542-4406-8f32-7854fe030292/Polybase/data_24b40621-2542-4406-8f32-7854fe030292_b592f424-dd7b-47af-925f-a2934aea4b67.txt)Column ordinal: 7, Expected data type: DECIMAL(18,3), Offending value: \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\

We can easily resolve this error by using ISNULL(COLUMNNAME, 0) in Source Query but we don't want to do that.

On Azure official Feedback site, this issue seems under review since long.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/10600192-polybase-fix-file-format-type-default-for-decima

Comment: Had the same issue, is the source a sql query or stored proc? If it is you may need to create mapping between the source and sink. If that does not work you may have to disable polybase.

Answer (score 2):

It is weird, the documentation talks a lot about nulls when source is data lake store or blob storage, but doesn't say a thing when source is another database. Reading in the polybase documentation shows that Azure SQL database is not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-2017

I would try disabling polybase to see if this solves the issue. In case it does, the performance will decrease but it may be enough to meet your needs.

Another way to work with polybase is creating a stored procedure in the Sql Data Warehouse that uses polybase to query another database and calling it with Data Factory, this way you will have more control over what polybase is doing.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: There is one setting at sink configuration on ADFv2 pipeline creation. we need to uncheck "useTypeDefault". This will transfer null value as it is instead of default values. This solves our problem

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Now we are facing issue for the empty string value. ADF treat null value for the empty string. Is there any way we can define treatemptyasnull to false? so we can transfer empty string as an empty string.

Comment: Unchek "useTypeDefault" resolve the issue, thanks for mentioning.